# SVG with 'svg' element embedded

Tags: svg

I've a problem with a complicated [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) image.

It works on Chrome and Firefox, but there is no way to convert it into a PNG image even using an online tool or [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) and also with [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).

I'm not sure where the problem is. Maybe because is it an image built with two other SVG images embedded.

Here is the [SVG file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yu2008tlpyzko63/stackOverflowExcample.svg?dl=0).

To reproduce the problem: open the SVG file linked with a browser: it works.

Open it with GIMP and the image is empty.

An easier example with the same problem:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Some graphical objects to use -->
  <defs>
      <svg id="pippo" viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
      <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="5" />
    </svg>

    <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="gold" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <!-- Using my graphical objects -->

  <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fc0" />

  <use x="0" y="0" href="#pippo" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

With SVG 1 you need to use the attribute `xlink:href` instead of `href` on the `use` element

```xml
<use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#pippo" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
```

You will also need the `xlink` namespace on the `<svg>` element

```xml
<svg 
  viewBox="0 0 10 10" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
```

Since SVG 2, [`xlink:` prefix is deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#XLinkRefAttrs) but SVG 2 is a [W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/) and all its features are not yet supported by all browsers and editors.

Full SVG 1 example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- Some graphical objects to use -->
  <defs>
    <svg id="pippo" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="5" />
    </svg>

    <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="gold" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <!-- using my graphical objects -->
  <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fc0" />
  <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#pippo" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>
```

Comment: unfourtunately it doesn't work. GImp open a yellow square with a black circle.

Comment: @DomenicoLorusso which version of Gimp do you use ? I use version version 2.1 and I can open it i.stack.imgur.com/NTCHZ.png I can also open it with Inkscape

Comment: 2.10 It seems to be a problem with the "use" directive...

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: SVG to PDF via the native browser feature "save to PDF" (print modal)

Since Firefox, [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)), and [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) have **powerful built-in PDF export** functionalities combined with way **better SVG support than any "desktop" application**, we can convert complex SVG images to a flattened, 'visually hardwired' vector file.

### Ideal result

- all vector data is retained (can also be opened in a vector application like [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape), [Adobe Illustrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator), [Figma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figma_(software)), etc.)
- complexities like nested SVG images or `<use>` elements as well as transforms are repositioned to hardcoded vector x/y coordinates.

### ... but curb your enthusiasm: common issues

- patterns and some complex gradients might be rasterized
- you will lose structural data like layers, IDs and other editable features.

### Manual SVG export optimisations

- as @Yukulélé already pointed out: some syntax conventions and newer attributes might be too progressive
- try to replace CSS-based styling with attributes – [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg) can be helpful
- reusable elements defined in <defs> or as <symbols> might have quirky recursive dependencies
- try to clean up unnecessary or invalid properties (e.g., hexadecimal [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model)) and fix incomplete SVG nestings (missing end tags)
- document dimensions and aspect ratios can often be better retained (by a graphic application),
  when the parent SVG element was added a **viewBox and width/height** attributes (at least in Adobe Illustrator)

Comment: it seems to be the actual  problem is the  USE directive, and I need to use this approach.

I've 2 svg that work. fine. I need to merge this 2 svg in one and be able to rotate the second.

I must keep the orginal image separted (to be easy i future replace or correct something), but however if I don't adopt a reference approach I've to move and resizeall the single oblects... I couldn't be the good approach